# XmlException was unhandled on C# Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, windows-phone-7.1, linq-to-xml

I'm attempting to open an XML file which is copied as content to the `IsolatedStorage` when I compile my app and am having some issues with it;

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 411.

I'm not entirely sure what this means and a trip to my local search engine only expanded my confusion, could anybody please tell me if I'm doing anything drastically wrong or if my data structure is bad please?

Here's my function that loads the data from the file and parses it into variables:

```
private void ReadData()
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (store.FileExists("appdata.xml"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("appdata.xml", FileMode.Open, store);
            XDocument document;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    document = XDocument.Load(reader); // <-- Error occurs here
                    ListBox listBox = new ListBox();

                    var data = from query in document.Descendants("myData")
                               select new DataHolder
                               {
                                   CashData = (string)query.Element("CashData"),
                                   LandGoData = (string)query.Element("LandGoData"),
                                   FreeParkingData = (string)query.Element("FreeParkData"),
                                   CircuitData = (string)query.Element("FullCircuitData"),
                                   AuctionData = (string)query.Element("AuctionData")
                               };
                    listBox.ItemsSource = data;

                    StartCashRule.Text = (string)listBox.FindName("myData");
                }
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }            
}
```

And here's my xml document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RootPath>
    <CashData>Value1</CashData>
    <LandGoData>Value2</LandGoData>
    <FreeParkData>Value3</FreeParkData>
    <FullCircuitData>Value4</FullCircuitData>
    <AuctionData>Value5</AuctionData>
</RootPath>
```

Comment: The document is about 200 bytes long. Since the message mentions "position 411" then either it is NOT the document you load or for some reason the document contain other data.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure it's the data structure that's wrong now because sometimes I get one error, the next time it's another error such as "Unexpected end tag. Line 1, position 421". What's up with the structure? :< EDIT: Oh, so I'm not loading in the file correctly? god this whole xml business is really starting to seem overrated as the standard for saving data in programs :/

Comment: ok, appdata.xml has no hierarchy other than the project directory in visual studio, should this code work with just that or am I better off creating a folder and putting the xml in there?

Comment: For some reason the parser complains because of something at position 411. Can't you just manually see what is written there, in the exact spot? The parser is extremely precise at its messages but you seem to ignore it.

Comment: It's a brand new file each time it's installed so unless my saving code is bad then there can't be anything there, wouldn't know how to read a specific part of the file anyway as this is my first attempt ever at xml, I'm a newbie at file data structures. Would it be best that I include my data saving code in the OP?

Comment: And could you rather open the stream with a `StreamReader`, extract the xml string and post it? I really, really believe that it has more than these 200 bytes and that you WILL find a problem at character 411.